# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Gateway' not found

Tags: php, class

https://github.com/alttantire/ptt-payment-sdk

I want to use the class in the link but I am getting the following error.

Error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Gateway' not found in /home/paylira/public_html/1.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/paylira/public_html/1.php on line 10

```
include "vendor/autoload.php";
use AkilliEsnaf\Gateway;

$apiUser = "Entegrasyon_01";
$clientId = "1000000032";
$apiPass = "gkk4l2*TY112";

$gateway = new Gateway($clientId, $apiUser, $apiPass);

$orderId = "123127"; // must be unique
$amount = 125; // 1.25 TL
$installment = 0; // No installment

$result = $gateway->threeDPayment("http://www.example.com/return", $amount, $installment, $orderId);
$threeDSessionId = $result->ThreeDSessionId;
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "weepay/weepay-php": "^1.0",
        "alttantire/ptt-payment-sdk": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like simply the first example of trying to reference a namespaced class - does referencing _any_ other class work or just that class? If you're using composer and [followed the instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) please edit the question to indicate that (include your composer.json in the question, demonstrate that dependency exists locally) and narrow down what aspect of "cannot find a class" is the problem.

Comment: When you're ready please address the rest of my comment (:.